# MYSQLI bind_param with Strato

Tags: php, mysqli

My problem is that my MYSQLI query a very strange behavior when it comes to prepare a query and then bind params.

```
define("HOST", "rdbms.strato.de");          // Der Host mit dem du dich verbinden willst.
define("USER", "USER");                 // Der Datenbank-Benutzername. 
define("PASSWORD", "PASSWORD");     // Das Datenbank-Passwort. 
define("DATABASE", "DATABASE");         // Der Datenbankname.

// Create connection to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset ($mysqli,"utf8");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {
    echo "success";
}
```

The connetion runs without any problem.

```
if ($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM accounts WHERE id = 1")) {
        $select_stmt->execute();
        $select_stmt->store_result();
        $select_stmt->bind_result($name);
        $select_stmt->fetch();
}
else {
    echo $mysqli->error();
}
echo "Name: " . $name;
```

Selecting the name of the aacount database is also running without a problem with binding the id directly in the sql query.

The problem comes up with binding the id with $select_stmt->bind_param()

```
if ($select_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM accounts WHERE id = ?")) {
    $select_stmt->bind_param('s', '1');
    $select_stmt->execute();
    $select_stmt->store_result();
    $select_stmt->bind_result($name);
    $select_stmt->fetch();
}
else {
    echo $mysqli->error();
}
echo "Name: " . $name;
```

The behaviour is like the one in an infinit loop.
But `echo "Name: " . $name;`is not displayed at all. The `echo $mysqli->error();` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you are only allowed to use variables for binding at bind_param().

Like:

```
$id= '1';
$select_stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
```